# How to provide control field in string.format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to convert data table in string format like this.

```
result += string.Format(@"<div class='searchbox'>
                <div class='{0}'>
                    <a style='color: #FFFFFF;'></a>
                    </div>
                <div class='{1}'>
                    <div style='width: 100px; float: right;'>
                        <asp:Image ID='imgLogo' runat='server' AlternateText='{3}'  />                           
                    </div>
                    ", dataTable.Rows[i][0].ToString(), dataTable.Rows[i][1].ToString(), dataTable.Rows[i][2].ToString()
                   , dataTable.Rows[i][3].ToString());
```

But i want to provide like this :

```
result += string.Format(@"<div class='searchbox'>
                <div class='{0}'>
                    <a style='color: #FFFFFF;'></a>
                    </div>
                <div class='dataTable.Rows[i][1].ToString()==true? "true":"false"'>
                    <div style='width: 100px; float: right;'>
                        <asp:Image ID='imgLogo' runat='server' AlternateText='{2}'  />                           
                    </div>
                    ", dataTable.Rows[i][0].ToString(), dataTable.Rows[i][1].ToString(), dataTable.Rows[i][2].ToString()
                   );
```

Please provide solution for this problem.

Comment: Shouldn't you be putting the conditional logic as a param rather than embedding it in the string? The code snippet also seems incomplete as there is no {1} or {2}. Updating your question may prove helpful.

Comment: where do you want to put ` dataTable.Rows[i][1].ToString(), dataTable.Rows[i][2].ToString()` butcause you have not mentioned `{1}` and `{2}`

Answer (score 0):

You should be using like below

```
result += string.Format(@"<div class='searchbox'>
            <div class='{0}'>
                <a style='color: #FFFFFF;'></a>
                </div>
            <div class='"+dataTable.Rows[i][1].ToString()=="true"? "true":"false"+"'>
                <div style='width: 100px; float: right;'>
                    <asp:Image ID='imgLogo' runat='server' AlternateText='{2}'  />                           
                </div>
                ", dataTable.Rows[i][0].ToString(), dataTable.Rows[i][2].ToString()
               );
```

### Edit 1

```
 result += string.Format(@"<div class='searchbox'><div class='{0}'><a style='color: #FFFFFF;'></a></div>
        <div class='"+dataTable.Rows[i][1]=="true"? "true":"false"+"'><div style='width: 100px; float: right;'><asp:Image ID='imgLogo' runat='server' lternateText='{1}'  /></div>", dataTable.Rows[i][0], dataTable.Rows[i][2]
```